# What is on the other end of the teleportation beam Steppenwolf uses?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, justice-league-2017

In *Justice League* (2017), Steppenwolf arrives and departs several times via a giant beam of light that shoots up into the sky. Where does he go when this happens? What is on the other end of this? Does he have a spaceship in orbit? Does he go to another dimension?

I'm especially interested in this given that in the ending

> he and his minions again depart in this beam of light, and if the other end is like his spaceship or something, that makes him very likely to be able to recover and resume his conquest, if he can get his minions to stop eating him.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That 'beam of light,' my friend, is a [boom tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boom_tube).

While it appears that the mechanics of the boom tubes have never been explained, they allow basically instantaneous travel between point A and point B.  Throughout the movie, Steppenwolf was simply returning back to home base to plan his next move.

As for the ending...

> The last boom tube doesn't seem to be by choice on Steppenwolf's part (I forget if there's any dialogue to this effect).  No, Steppenwolf is beaten, his weapon is broken, he's 0-2 against the forces of Earth, and parademons are nibbling at him.  The most common place boom tubes come from or go is Steppenwolf's home planet, Apokolips.  That last boom tube is Darkseid recalling a failed soldier.

Comment: I like to compare the "boom tube" to the same kind of device that the Asgard use in the Thor movies (the bifrost).  I mean they do the same thing and look almost identical in there appearance. I guess in movies there are only so many ways to whip up a wormhole.